# Trying to display fetched data stored in a state variable but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to get data from the link below by using fetch and store it in 'dataStore' and display.

However, it keeps giving me an error and I believe my code tries to show the data before it is stored in 'dataStore'. I'm new to coding. tried to research and find a solution past weeks but couldn't. Please help.

```
import "./App.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  let [dataStore, setDataStore] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGo-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json"
    )
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        const { pokemon } = result;
        setDataStore(pokemon);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{dataStore[0].name}</div>
    </div>
  ); // ending div
} //ending line

export default App;
```

Comment: A question asking tip:  It's generally insufficient to just say _"it keeps giving me an error"_.  Your question should also include the exact text of the error message you are getting.  Cut and paste if possible.  Error messages usually contain critical details that can be used to determine the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is trying to show `dataStore` before it is ready. To render the data when it is available, you should use **conditional rendering** (i.e. only render something given that a certain condition has been fulfilled). You can read more about that here: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.

Basically, check your `dataStore` length first, and if the length is above 0, then render the data. Should look something like this:

```
{dataStore.length > 0 &&
    <div>
      <p>{dataStore[0].name}</p>
    </div>
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can i love you? thank you so much

Comment: If this worked for you, mark as complete and consider upvoting.